# How do I merge by more than one variable using proc SQL is SAS

Tags: sql, variables, merge, sas, proc-sql

I have 2 datasets in SAS:

main_1

ID  Rep Dose    Response
1   2   34  567
1   1   45  756
2   1   35  456
3   1   56  345

main_2

ID  Rep Hour    Day
1   1   89  157
2   1   62  365
3   1   12  689

I can easily merge these 2 datasets first by ID and then by Rep (as one of the ID's has two observations) with the following code in SAS:

```
proc import out=main_1 
    datafile='/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/main_1.xls'
    dbms=xls replace;
    /*optional*/
    sheet='Sheet1';
    getnames=yes;
run;

proc import out=main_2 
    datafile='/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/main_2.xls'
    dbms=xls replace;
    /*optional*/
    sheet='Sheet1';
    getnames=yes;
run;

/*merge datasets based on common variable (ID then Rep)*/
    /*first sort all datasets by target variables*/
proc sort data=main_1;
    by ID Rep;
proc sort data=main_2;
    by ID Rep;
run;
    /*can now be merged*/
data main_merge;
    merge main_1 main_2;
    by ID Rep;
run;
```

this produces the following table:

ID  Rep Dose    Response    Hour    Day
1   1   45  756 89  157
1   2   34  567 .   .
2   1   35  456 62  365
3   1   56  345 12  689

I currently have the following proc SQL alternative (I am learning so sorry of its terrible) but cannot seem to merge by more than 1 variable (i.e. ID and Rep):

```
proc sql;
    create table merged_sql as 
    select L.*, R.*
    from main_1 as L
    LEFT JOIN main_2 as R
    on L.ID = R.ID;
quit;
```

producing the following:

ID  Rep Dose    Response    Hour    Day
1   2   34  567 89  157
1   1   45  756 89  157
2   1   35  456 62  365
3   1   56  345 12  689

Any suggestion on a proc SQL code to achieve the same table as previously? My current code adds the '89 157' to both ID=1 observations.

Many thanks.

Comment: Simple, just add the extra join-condition to the OB clause: `on L.ID = R.ID;` -->> `on L.ID = R.ID AND L.rep = R.rep;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there...

```
proc sql;
    create table merged_sql as 
      select L.*, 
             R.HOUR,
             R.DAY
        from main_1 as L
          LEFT JOIN main_2 as R
                 on L.ID = R.ID
                and L.REP = R.REP;
quit;
```

The reason not to use `R.*` is to avoid a note or warning about having duplicate ID and REP fields.